# Hadoop:Recognizing end of input splits in mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I've written some code in Hadoop that should do the following tasks:

**In the Mapper:** Records are read one by one from input splits and some processing is performed on them. Then, in accordance with the result of the work done, Some records are **pruned** and save in a **set**. At the **end** of the mapper this set must be sent to reducer.

**In the Reducer:** All of received sets from all Mappers are processed and final result is generated.

**My question is:** how can I **delay** sending mentioned set to the Reducer until processing of the last record in each of mappers. By default, all code that are written in Mapper runs as the number of input records (correct if wrong); So sets are sent to reducer multiple time (as the number of input records). **How can I recognize end of processing of the input splits in each mapper?**

(Now I use an if-condition with a counter for counting the number of processed records, but I think there must be better ways. Also if I don't know total number of records in files, this method does not work)

This is flowchart of the job :

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at using the `cleanup()` method which is called once when all records have been processed by the `map()` method?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I tested it and it works! I did not have any information on cleanup() method. Write it with details as the answer  (if you want). @Binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Mapper class](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.java) ([Javadoc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html)) you can see it has four methods available:

- `cleanup(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context context)`
- `map(KEYIN key, VALUEIN value, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context context)`
- `run(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context context)`
- `setup(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context context)`

The default implementation of `run()` looks like:

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    setup(context);
    try {
        while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
            map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
        }
    } finally {
        cleanup(context);
    }
}
```

This illustrates the order/when each of the methods are called. Typically you'll override the `map()` method. Doing some work at the start/end of a mapper running can be achieved using `setup()` and `cleanup()`.

The code shows the `map()` method will be called once for each key/value pair entering the mapper. `setup()` and `cleanup()` will each be called just once at the start and end of the key/values being processed.

In your case you can use `cleanup()` to output the set of values once, when all the key/values have been processed.